# Failed to find Build Tools revision 29.0.0 - Android Builds

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Now from my all Android projects, I can't able to export Android builds after updating library using Android Studio. I was, again and again, getting the same error:

[image]

This project does not contain any kind of external plugins installed. Then also I was getting this error, just two days before it was working properly.

EDIT: Android SDK tools folder content:
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For building a project, Unity3d uses a stable version of the Build Tools and not an **rc** (release candidate).

The Android SDK path is usually `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\` delete the **29.0.0-rc1** folder or move it out to anywhere.
You could also remove the **rc** version of the SDK Build Tools via Android Studio's SDK manager.

Doing that the project should build successfully.

Comment: Where can I find 29.0.0-rc1 folder? I have check SDK tools folder, nothing exist like that....

Comment: in build-tools folder

Comment: It worked perfectly, I can able to export android build now.

Comment: It worked for me too. However, after deleting the experimental SDK release, I had to restart Unity for it to have an effect.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8, Thank you very much, it truly did worked for me. Been migrating my Unity3D builds to Android Studio, in order to change this string value from "30.0.0" to "29.0.0", since I mistakenly downloaded "30.0.0 rc1 and rc2" while updating. Truly saved my time :-)

Answer (score 6):

You should download Android SDK Build-Tools.

in Android Studio,
go to **Tools** -> **SDK Manager**

in the left plane, select **Appearance & Behavior** -> **System Settings** -> **Android SDK**

now in the right plane Select **SDK Tools** after that in the bottom right corner there is checkbox called **Show Pakage Details**.

Expand the **Android SDK Build-Tools** and you can see the version of it.

Unselect the current version and Apply the Settings, You will ask to uninstall current version of build tools

And Select the version 29.0.0 and install it

[image]